# Lagrange's Theorem: Injectivity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $U$ be a subgroup of the finite group $G$ and $a\in G$.

To show Lagrange's Theorem we defined a map $U \rightarrow aU$, $u\mapsto au$ and said that it was bijective. Now for the injectivity we used the trivial case that for $au_1 = au_2\Leftrightarrow u_1=u_2 $ but this uses that we add $a^{-1}$ from the left side in both cases.

> Now my question is that of course there exists a $a^{-1}\in G$ but don't we need to have $a^{-1}\in aU$ to add it from the left? And if so, how can we show $a^{-1}\in aU$?

Best,
KingDingeling

Comment: What are the domain and the codomain of your function?

Comment: Domain is $U$ and codomain is $aU$.

Comment: How can a function whose domain is $U$ be defined as $U\mapsto aU$? And what is $a$ then?

Comment: $a$ is an element of the Group $G$. It's a basic lefttranslation.

Comment: Let U be trivial. Is $a^{-1}$ in $aU$?

Comment: That's basically my question... I don't know why I'm not understanding it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so essentially what you're trying to show is that if $au_1=au_2$ then $u_1=u_2$, and you seem to think that we are restricted completely to working within $aU$ to do this. But this isn't the case at all, in fact since $u_1$ and $u_2$ may not be in $aU$ (they are not in the case that $a\notin U$), so it doesn't even make sense that we could show $u_1=u_2$ while working entirely within the set $aU$.

The point is that these equalities we are worried about are occurring within $G$, so it is valid to use any element of $G$ to show this claim.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and explaining :)

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need to have $a^{-1} \in aU$ and won’t it by the way in mot cases.

This is by the way not required to prove the injectivity. The argument using $a^{-1}$ is not making that hypothesis.

Comment: But if I take an element in $aU$ to prove the injecticity, may I just use $a^{-1}$ even  if it isn't in $aU$?